# Youtube API inStream parameter is null

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I am trying to run sample code from the [YouTube API](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples). I am trying to run the [Search sample code for Java](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/Search.java). However, on line 70 and 71 where it says

```
InputStream in = Search.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
properties.load(in);
```

I get an exceptions saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:403)
at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.Search.main(Search.java:71)
```

I have not modified the code and don't understand why this exception is occurring. It is acting as if the file does not exist when it is in the place that it was when I downloaded the .zip file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not certain as to why this was the case but there was an src folder, which contained a main folder that held a resources folder, which apparently was what .getResourcesStream was reading from rather than the other resources folder. So I updated this new folder and the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem changing the original code provided by the API, and passing a single key inside the properties. Follow the code:

```html
 
 private static final String API_KEY = "XXX";
 
 Properties properties = new Properties();   
 properties.setProperty(API_KEY, API_KEY);
 
 // System.out.println(properties.getProperty(API_KEY));
```